# How to refresh v-data-table after REST API Patch call?

Tags: vue.js, datatable, axios, refresh, vuetify.js

I have a data table in Vuetify that is populated via a REST get request, using a function "getData" that is called when the app is mounted.  The `<td>`'s in the table have buttons that the user can hit to "lock" the period (the row/column intersection).

When they hit the button, they get a popup confirmation dialog.  When they hit "OK", there is a save method called to write the current date back to the db via a REST PATCH request (see below).

My problem is, the grid is not updating with the results of the patch request.  I have to manually refresh the page to see the result.  What is the common pattern here?  Should i pull down the data again via `getData` to refresh the table?  Should i update the array that the data-table sits on directly?

getData method:

```
getData() {
  var self = this;
  return axios
    .get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/estimatefinal/periods?dataset=capital")
    .then(function(response) {
      self.periods = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      alert(error);
    });
},
```

Save method:

```
save(item) {
  var self = this;
  axios
    .patch("http://localhost:5000/api/estimatefinal/period/" + self.id, {
      date: moment(self.selected_date, "YYYY-MM-DD").format(
        "YYYY-MM-DDTH:m:s"
      )
    })
    .then(function() {
      this.getData();  // ????
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      alert(error)
    });
  this.getData();  // ????
  this.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your PATCH changes only one row in DB, means has visually effect on only one row on your `v-data-table`, then  you can change the data locally when you get "success" response from back-end.

If, in other hand, your PATCH changes many other things in DB (also in `v-data-table`) your best option is probably to `getData()` after you get PATCH response.

Point is to keep that same "picture" of values in DB and on screen `v-data-table`.

Comment: So the safest thing, if performance is not an issue, is to just refresh from the db, correct?  For some reason calling getData from the `then` clause isn’t working above.

Comment: Yes it is the safest option if performance is not an issue.

But I'm not sure why your code is not working.

Add `debugger` inside `.then` (before call `.getData()`) and inside `getData()`, just to check how execution goes, where stops etc ...

(That would I do `:)`)